# Fusion Tables and KML limits, prevent download

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables

I have to display big amounts of data on Google Maps. Fussion tables could be a solution, but it has a limit of 500 rows/polylines per tile. I think that we can easily exceed this limit, so I need to find out another solution.

I think that creating a KML could be a good alternative. However, if I display the KML on Google Maps, then it will be easily accessible by thirds, and this is something that our client won't allow.

Is there any way to display a KML on a map and prevent others from download it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the difference between downloading something and viewing something online? Everything you expose in the web is being downloaded.

Comment: Would it be an option to set the minZoom of the map? Usually this limit will only have an effect at very low zoom-levels, where it doesn't make sense to draw a polyline at all

Comment: What 500 rows/polylines per tile limit you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be [FusionTables for Business and a private table](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2459324?hl=en)